# Getting mysql to run on IIS at startup

Tags: mysql, iis, service

I tried installing mysql on our IIS server. Currently to start mysql I run mysqld.exe in the bin folder and this seems to work. But when I log out the server, mysql seems to close despite the server still running. How can I make mysql run always as long as the IIS server is running?

I'm pretty illiterate when it comes to servers, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup MySQL to run as a service. (Services run whether or not a user is logged in.)

More info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-start-service.html